# Are values in STEP part 21 (ISO 10303-21) CAD files freely embeddable in entities?

Tags: iso, cad, step

Are values in entities freely embeddable in an ISO 10303-21 formatted file?

In all the examples I've seen that were generated from CAD programs, length_measure is embedded in uncertainty_measure_with_unit, like this:

```
#83 = UNCERTAINTY_MEASURE_WITH_UNIT (LENGTH_MEASURE( 0.0001 ), #86, 'distance_accuracy_value', 'NONE');
```

Is this ***required***? Could this be changed to, for example:

```
#83 = UNCERTAINTY_MEASURE_WITH_UNIT (#10000, #86, 'distance_accuracy_value', 'NONE');
#10000 = LENGTH_MEASURE( 0.0001 );
```

Conversely, we see something like this:

```
#91 = APPROVAL ( #92, 'UNSPECIFIED' ) ;
#92 = APPROVAL_STATUS ( 'not_yet_approved' ) ;
```

Assuming #92 is not used by any other entity, could this be changed to:

```
#91 = APPROVAL ( APPROVAL_STATUS ( 'not_yet_approved' ), 'UNSPECIFIED' ) ;
```

The reason I ask is, I don't have access to ISO 10303, since it is locked away behind many hundreds of dollars of paywall, and none of the sites dealing with STEP talk about embedding values.

Comment: You are absolutely right, an unaccessible standard is useless and the price is out of reach for anyone outside of the big players lobby...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume here that you use ISO 10303-203. The EXPRESS file modeling the AP203 is available through the [SCL](https://github.com/mpictor/StepClassLibrary) project [here](https://github.com/mpictor/StepClassLibrary/blob/master/data/203wseds/203wseds.exp). This is not the official ISO resource ([stepmod](http://stepmod.sourceforge.net/) is).

1. LENGTH_MEASURE is defined as a type in the EXPRESS file so it cannot be specified as an entity declaration.

   > TYPE length_measure = REAL; 
   >   END_TYPE;
2. Each entity shall be expressed on a separate line even if it is not used by any other entity.

You can get more information about STEP physical file on the [Depuis website](http://www.depuis.enea.it/page.asp?page=learning) or directly from the [ISO 10303-21 standard page](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=33713). [This wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303-21) can also help.